# How to force Robot Framework to initialize my custom library only once

Tags: python, robotframework

I have created a custom library in Python that one of the functions in the `__init__` module is `self.create_new_folder()`.

Robot Framework initializes the library twice:

- Once in the suite setup (I do not initialize the library myself,
  robot does it automatically).
- The second time it initializes the library is when it calls the first custom keyword from the custom library, and the test fails because the folder is already created.

I can check if the folder already exists but I would like to know if there is a way to force Robot to initialize the library only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE` to `GLOBAL`, the library will be instantiated exactly once for a test run.

From the documentation:

> GLOBAL - Only one instance is created during the whole test execution
>   and it is shared by all test cases and test suites. Libraries created
>   from modules are always global.

Example:

```
class ExampleLibrary:

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'
```

See http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-library-scope